# Chronometer not increment by one

Tags: android, twilio-video

I have implemented Chronometer to show call duration during Video and Audio call. Chronometer increase by one during the video call, but during the video call, it sometimes increases by one or two.

**Start Chronometer after call connected**

```
timeChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()); 
timeChronometer.start();
```

Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/call_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="16.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="23.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="16.0dip">

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/voip_call_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/calllogo"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/calllogo"
        android:drawablePadding="6dp"
        android:text="@string/video_call_label"
        android:textColor="#99ffffff"
        android:textSize="14.0sp" />

</LinearLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/caller_contact_photo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:paddingTop="28dip">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_photo"
        android:layout_width="90.0dip"
        android:layout_height="90.0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_img"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/whatsapp_icon"
        android:layout_width="20.0dip"
        android:layout_height="20.0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center|right"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:rotation="-10.0"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/name_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="16.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="20.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="16.0dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingBottom="20.0dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Mukesh Singh"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="26.0sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/call_status"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
    android:paddingLeft="12.0dp"
    android:paddingRight="12.0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20.0dp"
    android:text="INCOMING"
    android:textColor="#99ffffff"
    android:textSize="14.0sp" />
 </LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/top_bar_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:visibility="visible">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/top_minimize_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/voip_btn_background"
    android:contentDescription="@string/voip_call_goto_chat_description"
    android:padding="18.0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/call_minimize"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/timeChronometer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="18.0dp"
    android:paddingTop="24.0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="18.0dp"
    android:textColor="#99ffffff"

    android:textSize="14.0sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: You should add the code for the Chronometer class to your question, for otherwise we cannot answer it.

Comment: @AndrévonKugland Chronometer  is a widget that provides by Android Framework.